# On click in JSP, how to open a csv file using Excel in a popup

Tags: jsp

On clcking a link, i want to open a csv file in an Excel. As of now, it opens for me in the browser itself and there is no way to go back. I would like to open it in a popup using Excel.

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/templates/CSV_Template.csv">
    Click here for csv template
```

How to achieve this? Can this be done in JSP only using javascript?

I have added target="_blank" in href. But no luck. It is still opening in the browser. I mean it does open in a new tab. But i donot want that. I would like to open it in the excel popup.

Please provide your suggestions on this. I have a business requirement to acheive this functionality.

Comment: show what you tried till now i mean code for which you are saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `<a href="...>` then add the property `target="_blank"` and it will download on a separate window. 
For example:

```
<a href="http://www.mydownloads.com/get_csv.jsp" target="_blank">download CSV</a>
```

**Update:**

Since you said you tried `_blank` and had issues, you can redirect to another JSP which will have the following lines in the beginning (before you output the CSV content):

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition:", "attachment; filename=mycsvfilename.csv;");
response.setHeader("Authorization", utils.getSafeHeader(request, "Authorization", null));
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't feel it's a good idea to have a CSV download in a JSP. At least it's confusing, because I would expect a webpage being rendered in `get_csv.jsp`. Besides, your JSP will more or less consist of a scriptlet, which is no good practice either.

Comment: @f_puras I disagree, there's a website I worked on, and in it a reporting section. Each report could be displayed or downloaded in a few supported formats (xls, csv etc). Back then, I created an "Excel" button, "CSV" button for the download-files respectively. It was done with JSP and it works finetill today, plus, it doesn't confuse anyone (out of hundreds of thousands of users!)

Comment: I'm not saying that it won't work. And when I talked about confusion, I meant developers rather than the site's users (who surely do not care if `.jsp` is in their browser's address bar or not). In my opinion, a file download simply does not belong in a JSP, which is a view component and should not contain extensive scriptlets.

Comment: Well, yes - like [here](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/servlet-code-to-download-text-file-from-website-java/).

Comment: @f_puras since both of us know that JSPs are compiled into servlets, this is, technically, the same thing, no ? :)

Comment: Ok, you got me ;-) In the end, it's somewhat like deciding "which box do I put my toys in". If you do it in a consistent way, keep going!